# Need to open file through VB.net on another directory

Tags: vb.net, exe

Through my form, I open a .exe which is located in a folder inside debug so:

\bin\Debug\folder\ .exe

The .exe opens and creates 3 different files then closes. It is meant to create them in the same folder as the .exe but instead creates it in the Debug folder when opened through VB.net using Process.Start().

Would anyone have a possible fix for this so I don't have to move the files?

***EDIT***
(the .exe itself creates the files, some things may be declared outside of this sub)

```
Private Sub btnRunExe_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRunExe.Click
    If AcptEULA.Checked = True Then
        Localpath = Application.StartupPath() + "\MCserver" + "\minecraft_server." + txtVersion.Text + ".exe"
        Downloadpath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/" + txtVersion.Text + "/minecraft_server." + txtVersion.Text + ".exe"
        LocalpathParent = Application.StartupPath() + "\MCserver"

        Try
            Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles(LocalpathParent, "minecraft_server*.exe")
            Dim dir As String
            For Each dir In dirs
                Process.Start(dir)
            Next
        Catch
            'Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString())
        End Try

    ElseIf AcptEULA.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox("You must accept the Minecraft EULA before continuing")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: **1.** Don't hardcode the path. **2.** _Show us your code!_

Comment: BIN\DEBUG folder is the default folder where your programs run when in debug. This has no impact on a real execution of your program outside the visual-studio session. Please show the code that open the _exe_.

Comment: @Steve : It sounds to me that the problem is that he's hardcoded the path.

Comment: @VisualVincent Only the Code knows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process.Start could be used with a ProcessStartInfo instance in which you could set the WorkingDirectory property.

```
Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
psi.WorkingDirectory = LocalpathParent
For Each fileName In Directory.EnumerateFiles(LocalpathParent, "minecraft_server*.exe")
    psi.FileName = fileName
    Process.Start(psi)
Next
```

Notice that I have changed the Directory.GetFiles with Directory.EnumerateFiles that allows you to process a file while you loop over the folder files without loading all the filenames in memory inside an array. If you still want to use GetFiles then it is

```
Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
psi.WorkingDirectory = LocalpathParent
Dim files as String() = Directory.GetFiles(LocalpathParent, "minecraft_server*.exe")
For Each fileName In files
    psi.FileName = fileName
    Process.Start(psi)
Next
```

If you look at the [ProcessStartInfo documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN you could find a lot of other useful properties to fine tune how your program executes.

Comment: dirs is not declared in line five?